# Firebase analytics debugview events log issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I have a flutter mobile app which uses firebase analytics and Adjust analytics SDK. I have observed that there is a count mismatch issue for some events on both platforms.Firebase event count is always less than the Adjust event count for a particular duration and diff is quite large.These events are logged one after another in a single method call.

To debug and test this issue I have created a test application using Flutter and Firebase analytics integration. I used Firebase debugview to check if all events are logged or not. My observation is sometimes its not showing some events.

**Observation:** If I click buttons in below code in random order, some events are not logged
**Expected:** Each event should be logged in debug view

Does it mean that the events are not logged? Is there any issue in the implementation?

Flutter code to log events:

```
child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(name: "event_1");
                },
                child: Text("Event 1")),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(name: "event_2");
                },
                child: Text("Event 2")),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(name: "event_3");
                },
                child: Text("Event 3")),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(name: "event_4");
                },
                child: Text("Event 4"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
```